# How can I implement SSO authentication in a WinForm app and refresh the token every 2 weeks using Azure AD MSAL?

Tags: winforms, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, refresh-token

MsalUiRequiredException: No Refresh Token found in the cache.
AzureAD SSO authentication error in winform desktop application.

I am editing an existing winform app and adding SSO authentication to it.
The authentication part works and sign-in is successful.
However, I need to edit the code so active log in is only required once every two weeks. I created an authentication class and I'm using

```
   public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            try
            {
                var accessTokenRequest = PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, lastSelectedAccount);
                accessToken = accessTokenRequest.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Aquire Token.\n" + e.ToString());
            }
            return accessToken;
        }
```

where the last selected account is retrieved from a file on the user's computer but the silent token acquisition always fails, giving me this error:
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occured.'
Inner Exception
MsalUiRequiredException: No Refresh Token found in the cache.
Once the following method is called, the user is signed in and it works fine:

```
public AuthenticationResult interactiveSignIn()
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                lastSelectedAccount = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountAsync(authResult.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier);
                lastAuthenticationTime = DateTime.Now;
            });
            task.Wait();
            return authResult;
        }
```